# Priority for Apache Rewrite Module Matching the folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Vhost config:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin XXX@XXX.com
    ServerAlias  *.cccc.net
    ServerName   lolololololol.cccc.net

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
    DocumentRoot /home/someuserblabla/ccccnet

    #Rewrite abc.cccc.net to ./abc (folder). (hidden rewrite, without redirect)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.cccc\.net$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]

    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm index.html
    </VirtualHost>
```

DNS : *.cccc.net ==> 99.99.99.99

Everything works fine.

If you enter wow.cccc.net, but there is no that folder, The server will return a 404 Not Found.

The interesting thing is: Today, I'm going to add a folder called dev(/home/someuserblabla/ccccnet/dev), but It always return a 403 error, and this problem is immediately solved when I simply rename the folder.

I double checked all config files of Apache, It seems nothing wrong, And there is no "filter" for something called "dev"

After that, I remember there is a folder call "dev" in the system root.

Then I tried etc.cccc.net    root.cccc.net  ....

They all return 403 error instead of 404.

My Clue Is:

There is a order for rewrite module to match the directory. It search the root folder first, then the current folder.

Is there any suggestions? I don't want it searching the root directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your rewrite rule has `/` as the base directory, so that's where it rewrites to.  Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/someuserblabla/csuwnet/%1/$1 [L]
```